# Hide The Diamond Game - Hiding a dimaond behind one of 10 buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, user-interface, button

I am currently making a game called "Hide The Diamond", It consists of 10 Buttons and once the hideDiamond button is pressed, the diamond is then placed behind one of the random numbers\buttons. I thought I had got to a point where the game was running, however, something is causing it not to open. I have narrowed it down to the Activating of the event handlers at the bottom of the code. If i hastag all this code out then the programs open but obviously the game doesnt run. Any ideas ? Thank you.

```
# Find the diamond game / Importing the correct imports
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as msgBox
import sys
import random

diamond = 0 
guesses = 0

window=Tk()
window.resizable(0,0)
window.title("Find The Diamond")
window.configure(bg = "light sea green")

# Creating the button widgets and changing the appearnace and state.

Box1 = Button(window, text="1", width=10, height=3, bg="red", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box1.pack()
Box2 = Button(window, text="2", width=10, height=3, bg="blue", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box2.pack()
Box3 = Button(window, text="3", width=10, height=3, bg="gold", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box3.pack()
Box4 = Button(window, text="4", width=10, height=3, bg="dark green", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box4.pack()
Box5 = Button(window, text="5", width=10, height=3, bg="dark orange", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box5.pack()
Box6 = Button(window, text="6", width=10, height=3, bg="dark turquoise", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box6.pack()
Box7 = Button(window, text="7", width=10, height=3, bg="brown", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box7.pack()
Box8 = Button(window, text="8", width=10, height=3, bg="magenta", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box8.pack()
Box9 = Button(window, text="9", width=10, height=3, bg="medium purple", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box9.pack()
Box10 = Button(window, text="10", width=10, height=3, bg="lawn green", fg="white", state=DISABLED)
Box10.pack()

DiamondBut = Button(window, text="Hide The Diamond", width=15, height=3, bg="coral", fg="white")
DiamondBut.pack()

InstructionsLab = Label(window, text="Click the Hide The Diamond button to start the game. Then, click on the box where you think the diamond Is\
                        hidden. You have three guesses to find it.", 
                        wraplength=300, justify=LEFT, anchor=W, bg = "light sea green")


# Positioning the Buttons on the grid.

Box1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=20)
Box2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
Box3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
Box4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)
Box5.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10)
Box6.grid(row=1, column=0)
Box7.grid(row=1, column=1)
Box8.grid(row=1, column=2)
Box9.grid(row=1, column=3)
Box10.grid(row=1, column=4)

DiamondBut.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=20)

InstructionsLab.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=10)


# Create the event Handlers.
def oneC():
    boxNumber = 1
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def twoC():
    boxNumber = 2
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def threeC():
    boxNumber = 3
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def fourC():
    boxNumber = 4
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def fiveC():
    boxNumber = 5
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def sixC():
    boxNumber = 6
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def sevenC():
    boxNumber = 7
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def eightC():
    boxNumber = 8
    CheckGuess(boxNumber)
def nineC():
    boxNumber = 9
    checkGuess(boxNumber)
def tenC():
    boxNumber = 10
    checkGuess(boxNumber)

# The Check Guess Function.
def checkGuess(boxNumber):
    if boxNumber == diamond:
        yesNo = msgBox.askyesno("You did it! Congratulations", "Would you like to play again?")
        if yesNo == 1:
            hideDiamond()
        else:
            sys.exit()
    else:
        msgBox.showinfo("It's not here", "Sorry, try again.")
        global guesses
        guesses += 1
        if guesses == 3:
            msgBox.showinfo("No more guesses..", \
            "You ran out of guesses.\nThe diamond was in box number " \
            + str(diamond) + ".")
            yesNo = msgBox.askyesno("Play again?", "Would you like to play again?")
            if yesNo == 1:
                hideDiamond()
            else:
                sys.exit()
            
def hideDiamond():
    global guesses
    guesses = 0
    global diamond
    diamond = int(random.randint(1, 10))
    msgBox.showinfo("The Diamond has been hidden!.. Good Luck.")
    Box1.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box2.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box3.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box4.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box5.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box6.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box7.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box8.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box9.configure(state=NORMAL)
    Box10.configure(state=NORMAL)
    DiamondBut.configure(state=DISABLED)

# Activate the Event Handlers
Box1.configure(command=onec)
Box2.configure(command=twoC)
Box3.configure(command=threeC)
Box4.configure(command=fourC)
Box5.configure(command=fiveC)
Box6.configure(command=sixC)
Box7.configure(command=sevenC)
Box8.configure(command=eightC)
Box9.configure(command=nineC)
Box10.configure(command=tenC)
DiamondBut.configure(command=hideDiamond)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why my program wouldnt run.. It should have been command=oneC, but i had command=onec. The c wasnt capital. I have been looking at this code for so long lmao